# i would like to Convert Delimited Text Files To Excel Spreadsheets using SQLCMD in .bat or .sql

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlcmd

Any clues? currently my .bat files is like this.

```
del *.txt /q


sqlcmd -S TGS-TMS -i c:\scripts\followup.sql -o %date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.csv -s ; -W -u

pause

sendemail -f test@testing.com -t test2@testing.com;test3@testing.com -u TMS Daily Reservation Followup -m Please find attached for your reference. -a %date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.csv -s 192.168.1.32
move /y *.csv archive

pause
```

it comes out in delimited form... am i able to make it send in excel spreadsheet instead of a delimited form?
Do i change the code in the .sql files or the .bat files?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Some options:

- [Use SSIS](http://cavemansblog.wordpress.com/2009/04/17/ssis-export-data-from-sql-server-2005-to-excel/) to export your data to .XLS
- Use PowerShell, C# etc. to generate the file using the [Excel object model](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff194068.aspx)
- Use a [reporting tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159106%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)
- Use a templating tool and your preferred language to generate a formatted email in HTML

Exporting data using only SQLCMD and batch files is obviously possible, but only in a very basic way and it is not a method I would use to deliver data to end users. Sooner or later someone will ask you to 'improve' the email report in some way (typically by adding some formatting, totals etc.) and you will quickly reach the limits of what pure SQL and batch can achieve.